# Problem using SmartTabs in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs, auto-indent

I'm trying to use `smarttabs.el` from https://gist.github.com/188961 in latest emacs-dev (bzr). When trying to compile or load it I get the error:

```
smarttabs.el:54:1:Error: Don't know how to make a localized variable an alias
```

which is completely new to me. How do I correct this?

Also see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs for package explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is trying to say that `defvaralias` (used in the `smart-tabs-advice` macro) doesn't do what [jacius](https://gist.github.com/jacius) thinks it does.  But I'm not quite sure what he thinks it does, so I'm not sure how to fix it.  Try reporting the error to him.

Comment: I have posted a message to jacius on github. Thanks anyway.